VS Code not accepting Python Methods
I'm new to Visual Studio Code & Python.
I was following a youtube training session to create a basic test case to test amazon.
When I run the below Python scripts nothing happens when I run the debugger.
from selenium import webdriver                              #Opens Webdriver                 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By                 #Identified Elements on a Webpage
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys             #Keys Class
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#import pytest

class TestAmazonCart:           #create Class with self
    
    driver = ''     
    
    def setup_method(self):                    
        #self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()         
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")        
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)                     
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)                                              
        self.driver.maximize_window()                                               
        self.driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/")  

If I remove the  def setup_method(self):, remove the references to self and remove the indents it works as expected.

This isn't really a VS Code issue (unless I've misunderstood) - perhaps Python method not running when I run script would be a better title.

Hi, As mentioned I'm a beginner and as the code in the YouTube training video was the same as mine (I believe they were using PyCharm) and it worked then it seem to be an issue with the tool/extensions/how I was using it

Your script does not instantiate the class (TestAmazonCart) or call the method (setup_method). By wrapping your script in a class/method you are effectively giving python the recipe, but not telling it to make the pie.
Try adding at the end of your script:

test_amazon_cart = TestAmazonCart()
test_amazon_cart.setup_method()


test_amazon_cart is then the object created by the class constructor. You can call it whatever you like.
You then can call the method setup_method which will run the code you've defined in setup_method.

Thanks for the message, I didn't get a chance to try above yet but can I ask why the training video didnt need to make these additions to the script? Btw The script I shared is just the first method shown in the video just to demo the issue https://youtu.be/DWvsuQzdcXw?si=SxR-3ZA5JSc1ffRD

Hi, I tried your suggestion and it works, but I'm still confused as to why the youtube course didn't need to add those at the end of their script?

The youtube video is showing you how to write unit tests as part of and automated quality assurance (QA) process. If you followed the tutorial in the video this would work. Note that video isn't aimed at python beginners, just beginners to automated testing.

thanks for the help. The only setting I couldn't do was at 6:05 https://youtu.be/Sj7-QpRPyIo?si=Jjo9Le7L2yA-yEi4, would you know how I can do similiar in VS Code so be able to test like the video.

That's a different question - try posting it in a specific VS code channel (it's possibly not a stack overflow type question - you may need to find some kind of vs code forum)
